# Trying to read the rows if a particular row value of a column matches in csv file

Tags: python, csv, bigdata

```
import csv

with open("merged_data_1000_with_index_0.csv","r") as source:

    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result_test.csv","w") as result:
        for r in rdr:
            if rdr['campaign_name'] == 'disney':
                print()
```

I have a large dataset, I was trying to take out rows and write into new csv. The goal is to pick rows based on one column values, if it matches then append the row. ( I was first testing with print) However, I am getting error:

> ```
> if rdr['campaign_name'] == 'disney':
> ```
>
> TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

[image]

Comment: The most obvious approach I can think of is to use the pandas [read_csv method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Is there a reason that you're not doing that?

Comment: I cannot use pandas as the data is of size 160gb

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance, you could copy the first few lines of your csv and type out the desired output. Format all of this as code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

The csv reader doesn't keep track of the column names; you have to do that yourself. Assuming that the first line of the csv is the header, the rest is the data, and there are no extra spaces, the following should work.

```
import csv

with open("merged_data_1000_with_index_0.csv","r") as source:
    with open("result_test.csv","w") as result:
        rdr= csv.reader(source)
        wrtr = csv.writer(result)
        header = rdr.readline()
        idx = header.index('campaign_name')
        for r in rdr:
            if rdr[idx] == 'disney':
                wrtr.writerow(r)
```

Comment: I cannot use data, I working on 260Gb data file

Comment: I am trying to compare two large CSV files( 260Gb and 16gb) , I have two approaches in mind,

1. taking out particular columns(using column numbers), append to new csv. I think it might reduce size and then I will be to create chunks

2. each time run a code to extract a set of columns based on a one column value, eg: 
if col['name'] == 'disney' , then take out rows matching that value and append to new csv. 
Finally comparing new csv with 16gb csv file. 

Any suggestions on what would be the best approach here?

Comment: @krk See my latest edit